# File recovery: How can I make a non-destructive copy of a (NTFS) partition?

Tags: ntfs, dd, file-recovery

I want to recover some deleted files from a *healthy* **NTFS** partition on an *undamaged* hard-disk.

In order to leave the partition *undisturbed*, i plan to use `dd` to clone the partition to a raw image file & then attempt recovery from that mounted clone.

Will `dd if=/dev/sd<xn> of=/path/to/output.img` perform a non-destructive copy ?

Is attempting a restore from a clone using `dd` the best approach?

*[edit, [wrt Deltiks answer](https://superuser.com/questions/442837/how-can-i-make-a-non-destructive-copy-of-a-ntfs-partition/442844#442844), i need to be a bit clearer about what i'm asking]*

eg: are there some s/w that can do something *more* with the original sectors ? 

eg: if it was a *damaged* hard-disk i am aware that *any* kind of read is potentially destructive. but assuming my disk head is not going to suddenly spaz out etc, am i reducing my chances of a successful recovery (at any cost) by using an apparently non-destructive *single* read of my *undamaged* hard-disk.

(btw: i am planning on using `ntfsundelete` & `testdisk` for recovery)

Comment: [Good question](http://superuser.com/questions/442837/442844#comment512885_442844), but I'm reluctant to answer it because I don't know *for sure*. My logic works like this: A professional data recovery service would try to read the data without opening the HDD first.  If that fails, the data should still be there because only read operations were performed, so the magnetic data shouldn't have been affected.  Then, they'd open it up and go through the challenging task of mapping digital addresses to physical locations.  And it's expensive.

Comment: a damaged HDD *can* destroy data on a read. it's mechanical. even  NAND degrades on reads *(read disturb)* ;) ~b/l: *any* usage wears stuff out! ~am still hoping a h/ware expert turns up & tells me, if for *military grade* data, a single ordinary read (`dd` or whatever) is the zen way.. for everyday data, i'm fairly sure that it is. ~ BTW, have now retrieved *my* data a-ok. i ended up using [sleuth kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) since it is *o/s* & i needed to restore file-names & sub-directories. ~worked very well indeed. &&BTW: thx for your input ~one of those +1s is from me lol ;)

Answer (score 9):

**No**, the correct command for a non-destructive copy of a partition is:

```
dd if=/dev/sdxn of=/path/to/output.img
```

`sdx` in `sdxn` should be replaced with the actual device name.

`n` in `sdxn` should be replaced with the partition number of the NTFS partition.

This approach is certainly very safe because when you have a copy made, you can easily multiply that image.  If you mess up one image, you still have others.  If your HDD happens to fail after the copy, well, you still have the copy.

Because the operation is read-only, **deleted files that may still be in there won't be touched**.

**EDIT (2012/06/28 23:00 UTC):** Notice the `dd if=`**`/dev/`**`sdxn of=/path/to/output.img`, which is the directory containing the devices.

**EDIT (2012/06/28 23:03 UTC):** After your edit, your command is now correct and will perform a non-destructive copy of a partition.

---

To help further users, or for "just-in-case" scenarios:

### If your partition was actually physically damaged...

Use this command instead:

```
dd if=/dev/sdxn of=/path/to/output.img conv=noerror
```

The `conv=noerror` will make `dd` skip over any areas that it cannot read.  Zeros will be written instead.  Note that if the partition is physically damaged, reading it may be *extremely slow*.  As I am writing this answer, I'm holding a 20.0 GB Western Digital Caviar manufactured on 02 June 2000.  It failed starting around the 18.2 GiB mark, and `dd` grinded almost to a halt while trying to read past that point.

**EDIT (2012/06/28 23:17 UTC):** violet313 brought up a good point in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/442837/how-can-i-make-a-non-destructive-copy-of-an-ntfs-partition-with-dd/442844#comment512878_442844).  You might as well read a damaged disk to recover data because you'll have to read the data sooner or later.  Hard drive recovery by physically tampering with the insides is costly, like [this service here](http://www.harddriverecovery.org/pricing.html).

If `dd` fails to recover the data you want, consider trying a more aggressive tool to recover your data: [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

Comment: yes, sry for wasting your time,, when i wrote sdx i actually meant sd<*whatever*> ~since i imagine this question to be of more general use than just solving my specific.

Comment: No, *I'm* sorry for the confusion.  I also meant to point out the `/dev/` part right after `if=`.  That directory contains the devices, which you had left off in your question.

Comment: ok,yes good point, i will edit ;)

Comment: cool. so how about the second part of the question ~is cloning the partition using `dd` & attempting a restore from the clone the best approach? eg: are there some s/w that can do something more with the original sectors ? also before i press ahead, are you absolutely sure about the non-destructive read ? eg if it was a damaged disk any kind of read *is potentially* destructive..

Comment: sry, to keep hassling you & labouring the point & so on (it's my fault for not being clear enough in my question ~will now re-edit). but i think your **23:17** edit is dubious; if a *disk* **is** damaged, there is a *very real* possibility that getting it to do **anything**, _even_ an ordinarily non-destructive read *may destroy data*. -so if the data is worth paying thro the nose for, it's best to stay well clear of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I'm 10 years too late (and maybe this option didn't exist then). This thread did show up in my search though. And dd is super intimidating.

Best Answer for 2022: Use ntfsclone.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ntfsclone.8.html
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ntfsresize.8.html
https://edoceo.com/dev/ntfsclone-transfer-windows

Example usage:

```
ntfsclone --save-image --output /mnt/storage/windows.ntfsclone /dev/sda1

ntfsclone --restore-image --overwrite /dev/sda1 /mnt/storage/windows.ntfsclone
```

Note: ntfsclone does not clone unused sectors and therefore it's not a good tool for recovering deleted files. My use case and solution fits the title of this thread, but not the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Maybe that's what he wanted, 10 years ago. TLDR. But the subject title is what brings visitors to this ancient thread today, and I think they'll be happy with my solution.

Comment: [ntfsclone](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ntfsclone.8.html) also has a "rescue" option. So, it might be useful for recovering files, albeit probably not "deleted files" like the OP use case. At the bottom of the ntfsclone manpage is a link to the [NTFS-3G driver](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki/) wiki. There might be another tool in the NTFS-3G suite that's perfect for the need of the OP.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I've added a disclaimer as you suggested. Thanks for the feedback!